# Nested json objects in Flexigrid

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, flexigrid

First let me say this is not my doing. I wouldn't have structured the database like this. Unfortunately, it is not possible to make changes to the database. With that said:

I have json being returned via url into Flexigrid. The url is returning results from a mysql query. One of those results is a json dataset.

```
colModel : [
    {display: 'Contact Name', name : 'closing_data', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
    ],
```

'closing_data' is json that was saved in the mysql table as json. I need to access one of those elements for display. Something like:

```
colModel : [
    {display: 'Contact Name', name : 'closing_data->Seller_name', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
    ],
```

How can this be done so that it can display specific elements of the given json? Thanks for the help!